# Embedding ARB assembly in GLSL

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I have a few shader scripts written in ARB assemby which are supposed to be used with OpenGL ES 2.0. Now I have to port the app to browsers and I am looking into using WebGL. WebGL does not accept precompiled scripts. So I am looking for the easiest way to reuse the assembly scripts. I am wondering if it is possible to embed assembly snippets in GLSL the same way we can embed assembly in C. As you might have guessed from my question, I am a GL noob. Does my question even make sense? Is there any way at all to get WebGL programs to accept assembly scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. GLSL does not use or interact with "ARB" in any way, shape, or form. Also, WebGL has no access to ARB assembly; it is *only* used by desktop OpenGL.

The way to use them is to rewrite them in GLSL.